# How to assign value for every consecutive duplicate elements in list in Python?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have below scenario.

```
list1=['10/22/2017 10:00','10/22/2017 10:00','10/22/2017 10:00',
       '10/22/2017 11:00','10/22/2017 11:00','10/22/2017 11:00',
       '10/22/2017 12:00','10/22/2017 12:00','10/22/2017 12:00',
        ....
      ]
list2 = [1,2,5,4,5,3,3,5,6,......] #(list2 size will be equal to no. of unique elements of list1)
```

My question is how to display list3 which has values like below.

```
list3=[1,1,1,
       2,2,2,
       5,5,5,
       ...]
```

Means for no. of consecutive duplicate elements of list1, each list2 element should be appended into list3 that many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can also use `collections.Counter()`

```
import from collections import Counter
list1 = [...]
list2 = [...]

list1_counts = Counter(list1)
# list1_counts is now a dict of {uniqueitem: num_of_occurences}

list2_iter = iter(list2)

list3 = []

for u in list1_counts:
    # for each unique item in list1
    c2 = next(list2_iter) # pick the next value in list2
    list3.extend([c2 for _ in range(list1_counts[u])])
```

Note that this does not necessarily preserve the order of the occurrence of unique items in `list1`

Comment: It is working now.I got response for my question with in no time.                   Unable to  vote for answers as I joined recently. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
list1=['10/22/2017 10:00','10/22/2017 10:00','10/22/2017 10:00',
   '10/22/2017 11:00','10/22/2017 11:00','10/22/2017 11:00',
   '10/22/2017 12:00','10/22/2017 12:00','10/22/2017 12:00']
list2 = [1,2,5,4,5,3,3,5,6]
convert = {}
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
   if a not in convert:
      convert[a] = b

new_data = list(itertools.chain(*[[convert[a] for c in range(len(list(b)))] for i, [a, b] in enumerate(itertools.groupby(list1))]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to achieve this.

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
list2 = [1, 2, 5]

sum(([i] * len(list(g)) for (k, g), i in zip(groupby(list1), list2)), [])
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5]
```

This groups list1 in chunks of equal elements (actually these chunks themselves are [key, chunk-generator] pairs), zips those chunks with the corresponding items in list2 and uses the length of the chunks and the items from list2 to assemble the final list, using the old `sum(lists, [])` trick which is not the best way to flatten a list of lists, but very concise. If performance matters, rather use a nested comprehension:

```
[x for l in ((i for _ in g) for (_, g), i in zip(groupby(list1), list2)) for x in l]
```

Comment: It is working now.I got response  with in no time.I can't vote for answer as I joined recently. :)

Answer (score 0):

My take using an OrderedDict:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dictionary = dict(zip(OrderedDict(zip(list1, list1)), list2))
>>> [dictionary[k] for k in list1]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

This has the advantage of keeping a dictionary of the values so it is useful if you need to translate keys to values again. The trick is to create an ordered set (an special case of the OrderedDict) before pairing the two lists in a new dict.

Answer (score -1):

I did a quick attempt using the idea of a counter that increments when the next element is different from the previous (I'm assuming the list is in order).

It works for the values you put in, you'd need to double check on a full data set though:

```
list1=['10/22/2017 10:00','10/22/2017 10:00','10/22/2017 10:00',
       '10/22/2017 11:00','10/22/2017 11:00','10/22/2017 11:00',
       '10/22/2017 12:00','10/22/2017 12:00','10/22/2017 12:00'
      ]
list2 = [1,2,5,4,5,3,3,5,6]
list3 = []

previous = None
counter = -1
for i in list1:
    if previous != i:
        counter += 1
    list3.append(list2[counter])
    previous = i


print list3
#[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: python already includes a fast `Counter` implementation in `collections` module.